# Publish and Subscribe do not work correctly

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-accounts

*Publish and Subscribe did not work. Please find the solution as an answer down below.*

Initial question:
I am trying to publish the facebook first_name which is automatically retrieved when logging in with the accounts facebook package in Meteor (stored in the user collection under services.facebook). I have autopublish and insecure removed.

What I have tried so far looks like this:

*Server side*

```
Meteor.publish("facebook_name", function() {
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, 
  {fields: {'services.facebook.first_name' : true} });
});
```

*Client side*

```
Meteor.subscribe('facebook_name');
```

What I am using in my template to display it is this

```
<div class="Name"><p>{{currentUser.services.facebook.first_name}}</p></div>
```

Before removing autopublish the name showed up in the template.

Comment: Have you tried {fields: {'services.facebook.first_name' : 1}?

Comment: yes I tried, didn´t change anything

Comment: Where is your subscription? Can you show the code?

Comment: It is the first subscription I have right now. It is in client/main.js so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem:

When setting up your meteor project in your client/main.js it will show `import './main.html';` if you are working with routing and templates and not the main.html template this will prevent publish and subscribe to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When user is logged in via facebook oauth API and the authentication was implemented using meteor accounts-facebook, then all needed data is stored in current user object ( Meteor.user() ).

So, the schema of user in your case looks similar to this:

```
{
  "_id": "Ap85ac4r6Xe3paeAh",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-10T22:29:46.854Z",
  "services": {
  "facebook": {
    "accessToken": "XXX",
    "expiresAt": 1454970581716,
    "id": "XXX",
    "email": "ada@lovelace.com",
    "name": "Ada Lovelace",
    "first_name": "Ada",
    "last_name": "Lovelace",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XXX/",
    "gender": "female",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "age_range": {
      "min": 21
    }
  },
"resume": {
  "loginTokens": [
    {
      "when": "2015-12-10T22:29:46.858Z",
      "hashedToken": "XXX"
    }
  ]
 }
},
"profile": {
  "name": "Sashko Stubailo"
 }
}
```

Thus, if you want to retrieve a name of a user, all you need to do is to publish current user to a client and then get username from user object.

```
// server
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});

// client
Meteor.subscribe("userData");

Template.templateName.helpers({
 // this function returns username
 Username : function(){
 // if user is logged in using facebook; otherwise user is logged in using password
 if   (Meteor.user().profile.name)
   return Meteor.user().profile.name;
 else 
   return Meteor.user().username;
}
```

Now you can display a name of a user in your view: {{Username}}

Here is [more info](http://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#meteor-users-collection)...

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! I tried this publish function, however it does not return any facebook data to the client. When I look in the console for the user object it only shows me the normal data you can always see (id, name) . I would also prefer to only publish certain data fields of the facebook information and not the whole user.